# Beamer: Bottom align every frame

Tags: beamer, vertical-alignment

Is there a way to globally set the vertical alignment of the contents in a frame to be bottom aligned? In other words, I'm tired of adding `[b]` to every frame:

```
\begin{frame}[b]
...
\end{frame}
```

I know there are class options `c` and `t` to center and top align, but as far as I know, no b option exists.

Any help would be appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[b]
This is bottom aligned.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This is not\ldots
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the  `t` key which is defined in the file `beamerbaseframe.sty` like this:

```
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% top
  \beamer@frametopskip=.2cm plus .5\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
```

To obtain what you need (bottom align)

```
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% bottom
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0.2cm plus .5\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
```

And your code become

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% bottom
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0.2cm plus .5\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
\beamer@centeredfalse
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is bottom aligned.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This is also
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Update**

```
\documentclass[b]{beamer}

\makeatletter
\DeclareOptionBeamer{b}{\beamer@centeredfalse\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% bottom
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0.2cm plus .5\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}}
\ProcessOptionsBeamer
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
This is bottom aligned.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
This is also
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Maybe it would be nicer to define a new option `b` than to redefine `t`. Would that be feasible?

Comment: Answer updated .

Comment: I find that still a bit of cheating, since you still re-define the `t` formatting option. So when using the global `b` option `t` doesn't work as expected any more. But I have seen that implementing a real `b` option requires a bit more code,